# I am trying to run Apache Airflow in one single container. So trying multi satge docker build and running into error

Tags: python, docker, airflow

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS builder

# Set environment variables
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.2.0

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Airflow
RUN pip install apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-3.8.txt"
RUN airflow db init
# Stage 2: Final Airflow image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432
ENV POSTGRES_DB=airflow
ENV POSTGRES_USER=airflow
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
ENV AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/airflow


ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/airflow

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy Airflow installation from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/airflow /usr/local/bin/airflow

# Install PostgreSQL client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install additional Python packages
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Copy the updated airflow.cfg file
#COPY airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.cfg
#RUN service postgresql status
RUN service postgresql start

# Initialize the database and create necessary users and tables
RUN airflow db init

# Expose Airflow web server and scheduler ports
EXPOSE 8080 

# Start Airflow web server and scheduler
CMD ["airflow", "webserver", "--port", "8080"] '''
```

Here i get error in airflow init db command
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I am trying multi stage docker build just to avoid this error but it stays !!!

I also tried to run service postgresql start before airflow db init, still same error !!!

I have tried so many thing but error is same. I know its better to run db in separate container but I am just curious to implement in one single container.

Comment: To have more than one process is called fat container and it not recommend. Is that what you need? Or Are you open to use the standard approach?

Comment: You are running init db twice. And it seems that the first time  is before you set the conn. Might be the issue

Comment: I will try @ozs ur advice

Comment: I am open to standard approach but just want to try this alternate one.

Comment: @ShishirHossain , you need to run the postgress service when run the the container and not part of the build. the best is to create .sh file with all the command that need to run when container in running

Comment: so u suggest that I make a postgres container and then while running the container I make an entrypoint with all these airflow command as a sh file ?